# jQuery Window Resize event not updating when using module pattern

Tags: jquery, resize

I am trying to a simple script whereby some divs are set to the w/h of the window when the page loads and also when the window is resized. Here is my code:

```
/* MODULE - RESIZE THE SCROLLER */
var resizeContainer = (function()
{
    /* SETTINGS */
    var s = {
        $scrollable : $('#scrollable'),
        $sectionWrapper : $('#sectionwrapper'),
        $scrollableChildren : $('.scrollableV'),
        $childrenTotal : $('.scrollableV').length,
        $navText : $('nav span'),
        $winWidth : $(window).innerWidth(),
        $winHeight : $(window).innerHeight(),
        fontSize : parseInt($(window).width()/10)+'px'
    };

    function init()
    {
        bindUIActions();
    }

    function bindUIActions()
    {
        s.$scrollable.add(s.$scrollableChildren).css(
        {
            width : s.$winWidth,
            height : s.$winHeight
        });

        s.$sectionWrapper.css(
        {
            width : s.$winWidth * s.$childrenTotal,
            height : s.$winHeight
        });

        s.$navText.css(
        {
            'font-size' : s.fontSize
        });

        console.log(s.$winWidth);
    }

    return { init : init };
})();




$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* CALL RESIZE MODULE */
    resizeContainer.init();
});

$(window).on('resize', function()
{
    /* CALL RESIZE MODULE */
    resizeContainer.init();
});
```

When I call resizeContainer on document ready the console gives me the window size, however when I resize the window the value is not updated. Can anyone help me understand why? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see what is wrong in your code, however, resize event got particular behaviour which made it call often twice (depending of browser). You could try this and see if its working for you:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var timeoutResize;
   $(window).on('resize', function()
   {
       clearTimeout(timeoutResize);
       timeoutResize = setTimeout(resizeContainer.init,100);
   }).triggerHandler('resize');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sadly this does not work on any browser I am trying.

Comment: Is the resize event fired? Test it using console

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. resizeContainer is called on doc ready which brings in all the values with s. When the window is resized it just calls the init() function within resizeContainer and does not reference s again. Here's my updated code that works:

```
/* MODULE - RESIZE THE SCROLLER */
var resizeContainer = (function()
{
    /* SETTINGS */
    var s = {
        $scrollable : $('#scrollable'),
        $sectionWrapper : $('#sectionwrapper'),
        $scrollableChildren : $('.scrollableV'),
        $childrenTotal : $('.scrollableV').length,
        $navText : $('nav span')
    };

    function init()
    {

        bindUIActions();
    }

    function bindUIActions()
    {   

        s.$scrollable.add(s.$scrollableChildren).css(
        {

            width : $(window).width(),
            height : $(window).height()

        });

        s.$sectionWrapper.css(
        {
            width : $(window).width() * s.$childrenTotal,
            height : $(window).height()
        });

        s.$navText.css(
        {
            'font-size' : parseInt($(window).width()/4)+'%'
        });

        console.log($(window).width());
    }

    return { init : init };
}());




$(document).ready(function()
{
    /* CALL RESIZE MODULE */
    resizeContainer.init();
});

$(window).on('resize', function()
{
    /* CALL RESIZE MODULE */
    resizeContainer.init();
});
```

Hope this makes sense.